# SQLAlchemy - Try Except for different Integrity Errors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy raises a `IntegrityError` for both Unique constraint and Foreign Key contraint violations. How can I wrap this in a `try/except` block and discriminate between the various causes of the exception? I want to know which column the violation occurred and whether or not it was a Unique or a Foriegn Key violation.

Take this class for example.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    org_id = db.column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company_id')
```

The following could result in one of two different message:

1. if the `name` is not unique, the message is (x.IntegrityError) column name is not unique
2. if the `org_id` is not unique, the message is (x.IntegrityError) foreign key constraint failed

I suppose I could parse out "unique" and the column name in the 1st case. In the second case I could parse out "foreign key", but I couldn't get the column name. If the table has multiple foreign keys on it, how can I tell where the violation happened without making another call to each parent table?

```
user = User(name='Matthew Moisen', org_id=999)
db.session.add(user)
try:
    db.session.commit()
except IntegrityError as ex:
    # This gives either:
    #    (x.IntegrityError) column name is not unique
    #    (x.IntegrityError) foreign key constraint failed
    logger.exception(ex.message)
```

Comment: It depends on the backend. If you inspect `ex.orig` you can look at the original DBAPI error, which may contain the affected column, depending on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

you're absolutely right, you need to parse out the errors and it's database-specific. Here is an example you can use with MySQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

class MyUser(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'MyUser'  
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(64))
  org_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Company.company_id'))
  # notice how we define UK here :   
  __table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint('name', name='MyUser_uk_1'),
  )

class UserTest(unittest2.TestCase):

  def commit_try_cath(self):
    try:
      self.session.commit()
    except IntegrityError, e:
      if e.orig[1].startswith('Duplicate entry'):
        # make it a little prettie, this is just an example :
        uk_columns = [i._pending_colargs for i in self.session.identity_map.values()[0].__table_args__ if isinstance(i, (UniqueConstraint, ))]
        print("UK vialation for one of the UK columns: {0}".format(uk_columns))
        self.session.rollback()
      elif 'foreign key constraint fails' in e.orig[1]:
        # make it a little prettie, this is just an example :
        fks = [i for i in self.session.identity_map.values()[0].__table__.foreign_keys]
        print("FK vialation for one of the FK columns: {0}".format(fks))
        self.session.rollback()
    except Exception, e:
      print("Somethig else")

  def test_try_catch(self):
    # first user should go through :
    user_01 = MyUser(name='unittest', org_id=1)
    self.session.add(user_01)
    self.commit_try_cath()
    # UK vialation, dup name :
    user_02 = MyUser(name='unittest', org_id=1)
    self.session.add(user_02)
    self.commit_try_cath()
    # FK vialation, org_id 0 doesn't exist :
    user_03 = MyUser(name='unittest_new', org_id=0)
    self.session.add(user_03)
    self.commit_try_cath()

$ nosetests -v -s user_test.py:UserTest.test_try_catch
test_dev_debug (user_test.UserTest) ... 
UK vialation for one of the UK columns: [['name']]
FK vialation for one of the FK columns: [ForeignKey('Company.company_id')]
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.370s
```